# Two Sudoku tables side by side

Tags: tables, beamer, matrices, sudoku

I'm working with a Shidoku table, which is a 4x4 Sudoku table. I'm trying to place two Shidoku tables side by side, with an arrow in the middle, as to show that I'm transforming one into the other. How can I do this?

I have included my code below, and you'll probably notice that I have hard coded some of the information in there. Is there a way to make a dynamic Shidoku tables where the size of the table re-sizes automatically? I'm trying to do this in Beamer (using ShareLaTeX) and LaTeX. I'm new to LaTeX, so any help is much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{sudoku}

\newcolumntype{P}{%
\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{30pt}\centering\Huge\sffamily}p{19pt}

\newcommand\TPLine{\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}}

\newcounter{shrow}
\newenvironment{shidoku}
  {\setcounter{shrow}{0}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\newcommand\Srow[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=0 \TPLine\fi\stepcounter{shrow}%
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\tabularnewline
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=2 \TPLine\else\ifnum\value{shrow}=4 \TPLine\else\hline\fi\fi}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}

\\The Shidoku table: (This should be a comment)

\begin{shidoku}
\Srow{1}{2}{3}{4}
\Srow{3}{4}{1}{2}
\Srow{4}{3}{2}{1}
\Srow{2}{1}{4}{3}
\end{shidoku}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post *complete* code we can compile. If you are using Beamer, it is important that we know you are using a non-standard class!

Comment: Are you actually using the **sudoku** package at all? (Other than loading it.)

Comment: @cfr I just updated the code, which is what I have. Not sure what you mean by non-standard class, but it is just a Beamer presentation using ShareLaTeX.com. Also, I am using the Sudoku package, but that's not part of my question.

Comment: I just meant that `beamer.cls` is *very* unlike the standard `article.cls`, `book.cls` etc. So a solution for one won't necessarily work for the other. (It might, but it might not.)

Comment: @cfr I see. To my knowledge, it's just the standard one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using `minipages`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{sudoku}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{30pt}\centering\Huge\sffamily}p{19pt}}

\newcommand\TPLine{\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}}

\newcounter{shrow}
\newenvironment{shidoku}
  {\setcounter{shrow}{0}\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}P|P!{\vrule width 2pt}}}
  {\end{tabular}\end{center}}

\newcommand\Srow[4]{%
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=0 \TPLine\fi\stepcounter{shrow}%
  #1 & #2 & #3 & #4\tabularnewline
  \ifnum\value{shrow}=2 \TPLine\else\ifnum\value{shrow}=4 \TPLine\else\hline\fi\fi}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}

The Shidoku table: (This should be a comment)

\begin{minipage}{.42\textwidth}
\begin{shidoku}
\Srow{1}{2}{3}{4}
\Srow{3}{4}{1}{2}
\Srow{4}{3}{2}{1}
\Srow{2}{1}{4}{3}
\end{shidoku}
\end{minipage}
{\Huge$\rightarrow$}
\begin{minipage}{.42\textwidth}
\begin{shidoku}
\Srow{1}{2}{3}{4}
\Srow{3}{4}{1}{2}
\Srow{4}{3}{2}{1}
\Srow{2}{1}{4}{3}
\end{shidoku}
\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]